# Trying to extract value from html page using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

I am new to python and beautiful soup, but i got page like

```
<div class='pid-details'><p>
  <span>Drug:</span> <a href='/search.php?searchterm=amantadine&amp;referer=pillid'>Amantadine Hydrochloride</a><br />
  <span>Strength:</span> 100 mg<br/>
  <span>Pill Imprint:</span> <a href='/imprints/c-122-6021.html'>C-122</a><br /><span>Color:</span> Yellow<br /><span>Shape:</span> Capsule-shape</p>
  <a class='input-button small' href='/imprints/c-122-6021.html'>View Images &amp; Details</a>
  <a class='input-button input-button-outline-grey small' href='/imprints/c-122-6021.html?printable=1' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'><i class='icon icon-print'></i>Print</a>
</div>
```

and my aim is to extract value inside tag

```
<a href='/search.php?searchterm=amantadine&amp;referer=pillid'>Amantadine Hydrochloride</a>
```

so result should be

```
"Amantadine Hydrochloride"
```

Kindly guide me so that i start crawling. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am reffereing to some website how this can be done like guru99,etc.

Comment: Have You tried to write some code? SO is place where You ask specific question when You hit a wall, not a place where someone will write code instead of You.

Comment: Are you trying this url : https://www.drugs.com/amantadine-images.html? then. Include the same in your example.

Comment: i wrote and its working,

Comment: Thanks i think i am gonna close this question

Comment: If you get working code, Please answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. This code returns a list (found) with the inside tags

```
        page = '<div class=\'pid-details\'><p>\
                  \<span>Drug:</span> <a href=\'/search.php?searchterm=amantadine&amp;referer=pillid\'>Amantadine Hydrochloride</a><br />\
                  <span>Strength:</span> 100 mg<br/>\
                  <span>Pill Imprint:</span> <a href=\'/imprints/c-122-6021.html\'>C-122</a><br /><span>Color:</span> Yellow<br /><span>Shape:</span> Capsule-shape</p>\
                  <a class=\'input-button small\' href=\'/imprints/c-122-6021.html\'>View Images &amp; Details</a>\
                  <a class=\'input-button input-button-outline-grey small\' href=\'/imprints/c-122-6021.html?printable=1\' rel=\'nofollow\' target=\'_blank\'><i class=\'icon icon-print\'>\
                  </i>Print</a>\
                </div>'

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')  

        found = []

        hrefs = soup.find_all('a')
        p = re.compile('<a href.*>(.*)</a>', re.IGNORECASE)
        for h in hrefs:
            m = re.search(p,str(h)) 
            if m:
                found.append(m.group(1))

        found
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort

Comment: No prob! -If it was a worthy effort you can upvote me also :)